# Linux blank screen on laptop, but external hdmi monitor works

Tags: linux, nvidia, monitors, asus, zenbook

I have Arch and Asus zenbook ux431f with i7 and nvidia mx150.

After install -> blank screen on my laptop monitor but hdmi monitor works.

After many researches i've found this https://github.com/johnBerd/asus-blackscreen, and the result is the opposite -> blank hdmi monitor and internal laptop monitor works.

I tried also popos, ubuntu and centos. The problem is not the distro.

It's possible to have both monitor work?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I can't use my laptop screen with Ubuntu, Kali, or Parrot OS.

The only thing that seems to work for me is running Linux inside a VM ... however, I would like to have my Linux OS using the full power of the CPU rather than running through the hypervisor.